# modify content of flask page with another python script

Tags: python, flask

I have two Python scripts:

`tnk_flask.py`: This creates a flask webserver and two pages.
`pitoka.py`: this creates a random number.

My goal is the following:

When I run `pitonka.py`, I always generate a random number which I'd like to pass to `tnb_flask.py`, but, after refreshing those pages nothing changes.

What can be the mistake?

tnb_flask.py:

```
from flask import Flask # ezzel importáljuk ki
from pitonka import *
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
   denis = alma()
   return str(denis) 

@app.route('/tuna')
def index__():
   return str(numbi)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug=True)
```

pitonka.py:

```
from flask import Flask
# import tnb_flask
import random

numbi = random.randint(10, 100)
print(numbi)


def alma():
   return numbi + 17
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pitonka.py you are assigning the random number to a variable. So it will only get the random variable once. Instead return the random number in the function.

```
def alma():
   return random.randint(10, 100) + 17
```

Comment: Oh thanks, but main main problem was the variable-passing between py scripts. So for example I have an arg parse in pitonka, I give different arguments to it, and pass to tnb_flask, after refreshing tnb_flask, will it all the time writes out on the page the changing arguments? Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand what you're after.

Comment: ok, I'll try to implement it and if that won't work, paste here the pastebin link.

Comment: @DenisDore you're mixing two things. Flask is used for web applications. argparse is used for the command line. What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: from my android app I make pictures with my raspberry pi via ssh and i try  to upload to a webstite them with flask and ask the users in the android app to enter a code and I want this code to be in the url, this is why I need the argparse. Do you have a simpler soluton?

Comment: If a user needs to enter a code, they would need to that on the site, right. Then you need a form, not argparse. Search for some flask form tutorials.

Comment: In your android app, you'd have to make a POST request to a flask url with the code and then let flask handle the code appropriately. That's how flask can get knowledge about the code.

Comment: yeah, but the pictures are on the pi, i just want to send back a link to the phone, so the python script should make the post request, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could serve static pages via flask and re-render them from templates in pitonka.py